# How to get a single column data (one by one) from a database using c# and how to add it to a list

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008

I am using c# with SQL Server 2008. I am craeting a project, in which I want to read a number of dates from a database. These dates are stored in a single column as one by one. And the retrieved data should be added to a list.

My code is like this:

```
public List<DateTime> getholidays()
{
    DataTable table = new DataTable("holidays");

    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
    command.Connection = conn;
    command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
    command.CommandText = "select holiday from holidays";

    //conn.Open();
    SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
    adapter.Fill(table);

    List<DateTime> list=new List<DateTime>();

    foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
    {
        DateTime dt = new DateTime();
        dt = Convert.ToDateTime(row["holiday"]);
        list.Add(dt);
    }

    conn.Close();
    return list;
}
```

Comment: You have code but you haven't stated if you're having a particular issue.  Is something not working the way you expect it to?

Comment: What is the problem? Your code looks like it should work. (Granted, it could be optimized by using `SqlDataReader` instead of DataTables, but that doesn't affect correctness).

Comment: Looks ok, what data type is the `holiday` column?

Comment: nintoantony, are the dates stored with any type of delem..? show an example of what the data looks like might better help in answering your question

Comment: Where do you define `conn`?

Comment: @Dai the code is working,but the problem is that it olny takes the first value(or row) from the column.my column type is date and that column contains 13 dates.i want to add that all 13 dates to a list.

Answer (score 2):

For the sake of closure and spreading good-practice, you don't need to clear the DataTable before you fill it as it's a new object. In fact, you don't even need a DataTable at all if you use a DataReader. Here is how I would implement your code:

```
List<DateTime> dates = new List<DateTime>();

using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT holiday FROM holidays1", conn))
using(SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader()) {

    while( rdr.Read() ) {

        dates.Add( rdr.GetDateTime(0) );
    }
}

return dates;
```

Shorter, simpler, faster.

Answer (score 0):

i got a solution for my problem.thanks to everyone.
here is my new code

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        List<DateTime> list = new List<DateTime>();

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select holiday from holidays1", conn);
        SqlDataAdapter da;
        da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        dt.Clear();
        da.Fill(dt);
        for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            list.Add(Convert.ToDateTime(dt.Rows[i][0]));
        }
        return list;
```